# How to call request.security() only on first bar?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is there any way to run `request.security()` call only on first bar? Or at least on first N bars?

I have function that do some HTF calculations. It works right, but it has a loop, so script takes a lot of time to calculate.
And I only need it on first bar (for HTF perspective).

I tried global vars with bar index, time, arrays at `if CONDITION` but it seems like request.security() is called before rest of the script.

So is there any way to avoid this?

Here is the code that emulates the problem. Code with `var0` executes but code with `[var1, var2]` takes too long.

```
//@version=5
indicator("A", overlay = true)

var table t = table.new(position.top_right, 5, 1)
print(txt, i) =>
    table.cell(t, i, 0, txt, text_halign = text.align_right, text_size = size.large, text_color = color.yellow)

func() => 
    data1 = 0
    data2 = 0.0
    
    // if CONDITION
    for i = 1 to 50000
        data2 += high
        data1 += 1
    [ data1, data2 ]
    
func1() => 
    data1 = 0
    data2 = 0.0
    
    // if CONDITION
    for i = 1 to 50000
        data2 += high
        data1 += 1
    data2
    
// code works --
var var0 = request.security( syminfo.tickerid, "D", func1() )
print( str.tostring( var0 ), 1 )
// --
       
// code takes too long --
// [var1, var2] = request.security( syminfo.tickerid, "D", func() )
// print( str.tostring( var1 ) + "\n" + str.tostring( var2 ), 1)
// --
```

Comment: Is this your real code or did you share a minimal reproducible example? Because you might not need that for loop.

Comment: It's just an example and I now think it's not works the way I wanted. 

Basically, I have calculation on higher timeframe bars and script runs it on every lower timeframe bar. So it takes a lot of time. All conditions to run it only once I tried don't affect it or don't allow it to run.

Comment: My idea was that using `var` will force `request.security` to run only one time but it's look like it's not

Comment: Or it is, `requst.security` is weird and not consistent. Sometimes its work, sometimes not. I guess it depends on server load, but generally code with `var0` takes less time. And if we return  `bar_index`  from `func1()` it returns `0`